# I'm getting an "invalid filter" error with an LDAP3 search

Tags: python, ldap3

I'm just starting out with a direct connection from Python using LDAP. I can create the connection properly, but when I try and search:

conn.search('DC=MyCorp,DC=corp', '(objectCategory=inetOrgPerson), samAccountName="jdoakes")')

It returns the error message:

ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidFilterError: invalid filter

I've substituted other values for names here, but the actual connection works, and looking up that user via a SQL Query through LDAP returns as expected.

As I noted, I'm new to this but based the above on the LDAP3 example and the flags from the working query. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parentheses are a little off. There's an extra closing one. Also your filter may need to have an `&` applied to it. So instead of:

```
conn.search(
    'DC=MyCorp,DC=corp',
    '(objectCategory=inetOrgPerson), samAccountName="jdoakes")'
)
```

try something like this:

```
conn.search(
    'DC=MyCorp,DC=corp',
    '(&(objectCategory=inetOrgPerson)(samAccountName="jdoakes"))'
)
```